# How to use _repr_html_ with pyspark 2.2 and python 2.7

Tags: apache-spark-sql

***I run the following line at my terminal and I got an error, but it works fine in jupyter notebook.***

```
df._repr_html_()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1020, in **getattr**
>   "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.**class**.**name**, name))
>   AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_repr_html_'

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work on my terminal because it's not a visual interpreter, so I had to go through the data frame collecting the values I needed and creating a string like html. Then, I could attached to an email I send from python at the terminal and works fine.